# Is next day funeral a requirement?

Tags: sunni, death

In Turkish culture here in the UK, Turks generally get the body sent to Turkey for burial there. As far as I know we need to be buried the next day, but this delays that usually for at least one more day, sometimes more. Is the next day rule a strict requirement?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. I recommend you to take our 2 min. [tour] and check our [help] to learn more about the our site and model.

Comment: AFAIK neither of both are correct the body should be washed and prepared for funeral and buried as soon as possible this might mean in the same day if possible, however this can delay for reasons such as darkness (at night) for the next day!

Answer (score 1):

There is no strict law as to when the body should be buried. But according to Islamic law i.e; The Shariah, a body should be buried as soon as possible from the time of death, which means that funeral planning and preparations begin immediately.